# Use Flow Router Param in Autoform

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, flow-router

Friends,

I'm working on my first app in Meteor and hitting my head against the wall on something...

I have a scenario similar to a blog + comments situation where I have one collection (call it 'posts') and want to associate documents from another collection (call it 'comments').

The best way I know to pass the post._id to the comments as a "postId" field is to use the Flow Router params, since the form is on the 'post/:id' view.

But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get "var postId = FlowRouter.getParam('postId');" to pass to Autoform so it populates. I've tried adding it as a function in the schema, as a hook, and as a hidden field in the form on the page (obviously don't want to go that route).

Autoform is amazing and I want to use it, but may have to wire it up the hard way if I can't get this darn value to populate.

Any ideas? I've been hitting my head against the wall on this for a couple of days now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, just so we're on the same page, if you have your route is set up like this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/blog/:postId', {
  action: function (params, queryParams) {
    FlowLayout.render('layout', { body: 'postTemplate' });
  },
});
```

You are able to call `FlowRouter.getParam('postId')` from inside the AutoForm hook

You'll need to use an AutoForm hook *and* have a complete schema. I'm using the package `aldeed:collection2` for the schema set up. The `postId` field must be explicity declared. This code is running on both server and client.

```
Comments = new Mongo.Collection("comments");

Comments.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  comment: {
    type: String,
    label: "Comment"
  },
  postId: {
    type: String
  }
}));
```

Setting your form up like this is not what you want:

```
{{> quickForm collection="Comments" id="commentForm" type="insert"}}
```

That's no good because it will show the `postId` field in the HTML output. We don't want that, so you have to fully define the form like this:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Comments" id="commentForm" type="insert"}}
    <fieldset>
        {{> afQuickField name='comment' rows=6}}
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Then add the AutoForm hook. This code is running on the client.

```
var commentHooks = {
  before: {
    insert: function(doc){
      var postId = FlowRouter.getParam('postId');
      doc.postId = postId;
      return doc;
    }
  }
};

AutoForm.addHooks(['commentForm'],commentHooks);
```

Make sure you have your allow/deny rules set up, and it should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this same use case as well, and I found this on the Meteor forums: https://forums.meteor.com/t/use-flow-router-param-in-autoform/14433/2

> If you're using a schema to build your form (either with the autoform or quickform tags) then you can put it right in there.

For example:

campaignId: {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
        value: function() {
            return FlowRouter.getParam('campaignId');
        },
        type: "hidden"
    }
},